# Update from Crystal 2008 to 2013 Issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-community, crystal-reports-2013

my harddrive at work crashed and so they gave me a new computer instead of crystal 2008 they installed crystal 2013.

when i open my old report and run in the crystal app it works just fine.  however the c# app (visual Studios 2017 community) that i built which uses the crystal com dll (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll) keeps giving me this error ('The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula.
Details: errorKind).

The issue appears to be coming from a suppression formula (CurrentPageOrientation=crLandscape). I created a blank sample report with nothing but this expression in the report header suppression section.  again the report works fine in the crystal app but not in the c# app.

```
            ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
        report.Load(@"C:\Users\e212034\Desktop\Report1.rpt");
        report.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"v:\test.pdf");
```

so my question is why does it work in the crystal reports app but not in the c# app? I have tried different syntax's like (if CurrentPageOrientation=crLandscape then true else false) but no luck interesting thing is that just true works or if 1=1 then true works etc.  it seems to be the constants that are throwing the issues but i am not sure what else i can use.

Answer (score 0):

fixed issue by installing the crystal reports for visual studios sdk.

Comment: Please elaborate on the steps you took.  For example, where do you get the SDK from? What changes to it make to C# project?